# How would you implement a rich text editor with pagination?

Tags: javascript, pagination, rich-text-editor, page-break

As a part of a bigger project I'm going to implement a rich text editor with pagination.

Because of previous bad experiences with content-editable I would prefer the editor to use an approach with a document model (e.g., [prose-mirror](http://prosemirror.net/) and [slate](https://docs.slatejs.org/slate-react/editor)).

The editor is going to have only a handful of elements that the user can insert, so the amount features is not very important.

The hard problem here is pagination, which unfortunately none, of the otherwise decently looking editors I've looked at, support out of the box.

I'm confident that I'm capable of extending one of the existing editors with pagination support, but I'm also aware that it will require a lot of work, so I really want to make the right decisions from the beginning.

Given the provided information, which approach would you choose in regards to implementing a rich text editor with pagination?

Technical details and stories about past experiences with extending/using various editors are more than welcome.

Comment: Hey, were you able to acheive pagination in proseMirror? or did you find any other editor which handled this?

Answer (score 4):

We've done pagination with ProseMirror. It's a pain in the butt, but there are a lot of ways to make it work in the model - modeling pages directly, using marks to indicate page boundaries, etc - as long as you're comfortable writing custom views to support your chosen representation.

The key decisions focus on

1. How interactive does your pagination need to be?
2. How fluid is your formatting?

If you're ok with pagination that is "eventually" correct, and if you have rules that fix your characters per line (basically pseudo-monospacing), you'll be ok in PM. If you need your pagination to be correct RIGHT NOW and support diverse fonts, you're going to have to fall back on the browser's ability to measure your element sizes, which means a lot of "shadow" rendering.

You should probably also realize up front that ProseMirror is a relatively quick document engine, but with long documents where in-editor pagination really shines it still struggles to keep up with the workload. I'm hoping that the core can be rewritten in something like WebAssembly, which should offer a substantial speedup for the low-level calculations that ProseMirror is doing for this sort of stuff.

Comment: Hi Mike - I was just looking for a solution on how to approach pagination in ProseMirror (using vue wrapper Tiptap) - could you write a bit more on how you achieved paginations? Or maybe you've found some examples on the net? Would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: @AndrzejDzirba I can't comment on the specific implementation I worked on, as it's IP for that company, but there are several approaches that can work. The key thing to realize is that you're really looking at page boundaries rather than page elements, at least until you want to print the output. One approach I never got to try out is as follows: 

- each line has an end of line mark
- each page has an end of page mark
- as you enter new content, both kinds of marks get moved around
- nodeviews render from the marked content into HTML

Comment: @AndrzejDzirba You can also bake pages directly into the document model in Prosemirror, with each page a node in the document tree. That's a much less flexible representation, but the rendering piece of it is easier. Beyond that, I'm not sure what else would be helpful to discuss. The key decision is when and what to paginate at any given moment - if you re-paginate with each keystroke, things get very bogged down very quickly, obviously, hence my note about eventual correctness. If you're content to do limited pagination immediately and full pagination asynchronously, you're golden.

Comment: Aside: I really wish there was some level of formatting in comments on here.

Comment: hi, thank you. I've been playing aroung with some ideas and came up with what you wrote - an additional node-page element containing other elements as children. That was relatively easy. But - now I'm trying to figure out how to approach spliting content info pages with updates, and so far I had two ideas. 

1. recalculate after each stroke in onUpdate and then render content again. That may be slow, as you've pointed out, but in this approach I can actually calculate element's height based on contentHeight property of rendered elements - so it's quite easy.

Comment: 2. Second idea would be to somehow limit content of a node/page - calculate height of elements within a page node and then if exceeded create another node - but honestly I have no idea how to do that. In tiptap which is vue/react implementation of Prosemirror that implemented parseHTML renderHtml which seem to be responsible for that but so far I've been unsuccessfull in using those. 

What I also know already id that I dont need precise pagination the way google docs do - meaning for instance spliting tables. That is not an issue. 

Also - I think asynchronous pagination would be ok.

Comment: just realized that even if I tried to apply formating this comment system cuts them off

Comment: I would recommend, to the extent possible, that you not use rendered content to drive pagination. It works, but it's dog slow, and it introduces dependencies between the model and the view that make things worse. One of the reasons I tend to favour the marks solution is you can set a specific measure per line (characters/words in a font, for example) and move your marks when that measure is exceeded. If you don't need to be too exact, even better.

Comment: If you're ok with async pagination, you can limit your per-stroke calculation to the current page and only repaginate when you hit the end of it or switch pages - basically you'd push all content to the following page until it's time to re-paginate, either because the user has reached the end of the current page or because they're scrolling around the document.

Comment: One possible way to calculate content sizes is to hybridize the two approaches - initially, calculate the height of elements as you suggest in your first approach, but then cache those calculations whenever possible. Assuming a relatively small number of font styles, there are a pretty limited set of scenarios - first line in a paragraph, second and following lines, last line, line containing bold, etc. You can use the same approach to calculate line length as well.

Comment: Note that I haven't implemented the system I'm describing, but as the editor I was working on had pretty hard limits on fonts and formatting, this was the approach I advocated for, and I did some technical design work to try to make the case (though ultimately I failed in that attempt).